# Apache 2.4 .htaccess file doesn't deny access

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I tried many times with different methods, but i'm still unable to deny access to folder by .htaccess. Here is what i tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

<Directory />
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Second try:

```
RewriteEngine On

<RequireAll>
   Require all denied
</RequireAll>
```

Third try:

```
RewriteEngine On
Require all denied
```

What am i missing? Thanks

**EDIT:**

If this will help I'm using windows x64 version of apache. Downloaded here:
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/

**LAST EDIT:**

The problem is misspeled .htaccess name it was .htacess. Thanks for all of your time.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use this in your htaccess file in the directory; your 2nd and 3rd try.

```
Require all denied
```

The `<directory>` directive should be used in your conf file. Also this is not a rewrite so having RewriteEngine will not matter. This is part of [mod_authz_core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html)

It maybe ignoring your .htaccess file. Check your conf file and make sure that you have `AllowOverride All` because in `2.4` the default is `None`.

Comment: Unfortunately all settings are as you described. AllowOverride All. What can be other reason for this? I have LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so not commented in httpd.conf. How can i check if it working?

Comment: Yes, I see the issue was spelling. Yes that will do it. :)